# Error messages when trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04 from an USB stick on a Windows 7 PC

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I wanted to get rid of Windows 7 on my desktop and replace it with Ubuntu. I used a Sandisk 32GB usb stick and Rufus 2.16 to create a bootable usb drive. When I use my motherboard's bootmenu to select my USB it starts booting from the USB stick, only to be followed by this screen:

[image: photo]

I am running Windows 7 with an Intel i5-4570 alongside a GTX970 and 8GB of memory. Using Rufus, I have tried to check the USB stick for bad sectors but found none.
I have Googled some of the error message and I found people reporting this issue but not in the context I am experiencing it; some people have encountered this issue only after installing Ubuntu, not before. Can anyone shed some light?

Addendum: I'm encountering the same error when I tried Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future generations, this worked for me:

When the system boots and you see the purple screen with the accessibility icon and a space bar hit space, select advanced options and turn on the option -nomodeset.

Comment: I think it might be an uefi settings related issue. Did you tried to check the error message in combination with something like "advanced chipset features". I use ASrock motherboards and that's where I would look for such a setting if I was in your place.

Comment: @Marco In this case the answer is correct, `nomodeset`is what needs to be added and the OP is booting and installing in Legacy mode which is the most likely default due to the factory installed Win7. The OP could and should have installed in UEFI mode but the issue would have the same because it has to do with lack of proper support for this graphics model by the default `nouveau` driver, not with the mode. And this parameter is required until the Nvidia proprietary drivers are finally installed.